# Expected value is a theoretical concept while average of a sample is practical, is my understanding right?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[Expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) is a theoretical concept

In probability theory, the expected value of a random variable, intuitively, is the long-run average value of repetitions of the same experiment it represents. For example, the expected value in rolling a six-sided die is 3.5, because the average of all the numbers that come up is 3.5 as the number of rolls approaches infinity

most of experiments cannot actually get exact 3.5 by randomly rolling a six-sided die.

each experiment gets an average value, which is practical.

is my understanding right?

Comment: There is an axiomatic definition of expected value of random variable: the weighted average $\mathbb{E}(X)=\sum x \mathbb{P}(X=x)$ for integer valued RVs, and a similar definition for continuous RVs but with integrations and densities etc. That taking the sample average of IIDRVs converges to the theoretical value $E(X)$ is one of many versions of what is called the law of large numbers. This gives the frequency interpretation of probability some theoretical justification. William Feller’s book has an excellent introduction on this, by the way.